# Middle-Ware Technologies

Tags: middleware, distributed-system

As a Assignment our team have to develop a distributed system and we have to provide List of middle-ware technologies. What are the middle-ware technologies and examples?

Answer (score 0):

Here is definition of middleware: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middleware

> Middleware is computer software that provides services to software applications beyond those available from the operating system. It can be described as "software glue"

In distributed applications:

> The term is most commonly used for software that enables communication and management of data in distributed applications. An IETF workshop in 2000 defined middleware as "those services found above the transport (i.e. over TCP/IP) layer set of services but below the application environment" (i.e. below application-level APIs). In this more specific sense middleware can be described as the dash ("-") in client-server, or the -to- in peer-to-peer. Middleware includes web servers, application servers, content management systems, and similar tools that support application development and delivery.

Simpler answers are for example:

- Database middleware: sql*net(oracle), I*Net(IBM), ODBC Driver.
- RPC (Remote Procedure Call) middleware: DCE RPC etc..
- MOM (Message Oriented Middleware): MS series(IBM), BEA Message Q, JMS (based on J2EE) etc..
- TP-Monitor Middleware: BEA TUXEDO, BEA TOPEND, IBM TxSeries, CS TALK(Taiwan) etc..
- ORB (Object Request Broker) Middleware: IONA Orbix, Borland VisiBroker, BEA TUEXDO 8.0, COBRA engine etc...
- WAS (Web Application Server) Middleware: WebLogic, WebSphere, Tomcat...